# $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{\mathrm{i}tx}} {(\,t - \mathrm{i})^{n/2}}dt$, Fourier transform via contour integral with branch cut

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration, fourier-transform, branch-cuts

I am trying to evaluate the following Fourier transform 
$$F(x,n) =
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}tx}}
{(\,t - \mathrm{i}\,)^{n/2}}\,\mathrm{d}t\,,\quad
\forall\ x \in \mathbb{R}^{+}\,,\ n\in \mathbb{N}.
$$

For even $n$, we can use the contour integral on the complex plane $t$ where [the contour](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/93/ContourDiagram.png) consists of the interval $\left[-a, a\right]$ on the real axis and a hemisphere on the upper half plane centered at the origin with a radius of $a$ for $a > 0$. We obtain the result using Cauchy's differentiation formula.

For odd natural number $n$, there is a branch cut for
$\displaystyle(t - \mathrm{i})^{\frac n 2}$. Now if we make a slit from
$t = \mathrm{i}$ and integrate
$\displaystyle\frac{e^{\mathrm{i}tx}}{\left(\,t -\mathrm{i}\,\right)^{\frac n 2}}$ starting from $t = \mathrm{i}$ we will have a divergent integral for $n \geq 3$. What could be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We extend the original integral on $\frac n2$ by a complex number $\Re z>0$.
$$F(x,z) := \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}tx}}
{\left(t - \mathrm{i}\right)^z}\,\mathrm{d}t\,,\quad
\forall\ x \in \mathbb{R}^{+}\,,\ \Re z\in(0,\infty).$$

We have to make the extension to make use of the contour integral because of the subtlety of the convergence condition of the contour integral in different region is different. The convergence set for $z$  is the intersection of all the convergence sets of $z$ on all the different legs.  We use analytical continuation to make the connection.

> Lemma 1: Let $g(z,t)$ be defined for $(z,t)\in\Omega\times[0,1]$. $g(z,t)$ is holomorphic in $z$ for every fixed $t$ and continuous on $\Omega\times[0,1]$. $G(z):=\int_0^1 g(z,t)\,\mathrm dt$ is holomorphic in $\Omega$.

Proof: We show this via Morera's theorem applied to an arbitrary closed simple smooth contour on any arbitrarily given disk $B$ of finite radius in $\Re z\in(0,\infty)$. A continuous function on a compact set is uniformly continuous. So $g(z,t)$ being continuous on the compact set $B\times[0,1]$ is uniformly continuous on $B\times[0,1]$. We can use Riemann sum for the integral to finish the proof.

> Lemma 2: $F(x,z)$ is holomorphic in $\Re z\in(0,\infty)$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$.

Proof: We show this via Morera's theorem applied to an arbitrary closed simple smooth contour $C$ on any arbitrarily given disk $B$ of finite radius in $\Re z\in(0,\infty)$.

By Lemma 1, $F(x,z,R):=\int_{-R}^R f(t,x,z)\,\mathrm dt$, where $f(t,x,z):=\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}tx}}
{\left(t - \mathrm{i}\right)^z}$, is holomorphic in $\Re z\in(0,\infty)$. We will show below that for any fixed $x\in\mathbb R^+$, $F(x,z,R)$ uniformly approaches $F(x,z)$ with respect to $B$ as $R\rightarrow\infty$. Then
$$0=\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\oint_C F(x,z,R)\,\mathrm dz = \oint_C \lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}F(x,z,R)\,\mathrm dz=\oint_C F(x,z)\,\mathrm dz$$
by Morera's theorem, the conclusion of the Lemma follows.

To that end, let
$$\overline F_+(x,z,R):=\int_R^\infty\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}tx}}
{\left(t - \mathrm{i}\right)^z}\,\mathrm dt = \frac1{\mathrm ix}\bigg(-\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}Rx}}
{\left(R - \mathrm{i}\right)^z}+z\int_R^\infty\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}tx}}
{\left(t - \mathrm{i}\right)^{1+z}}\,\mathrm dt\bigg)$$
and
$$\overline F_-(x,z,R):=\int_R^\infty\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}tx}}
{\left(-(t+\mathrm{i})\right)^z}\,\mathrm dt = \frac1{\mathrm ix}\bigg(\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}Rx}}
{\left(-(R - \mathrm{i})\right)^z}+z\int_R^\infty\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}tx}}
{\left(-(t - \mathrm{i})\right)^{1+z}}\,\mathrm dt\bigg)$$

Note: The integration by parts is needed because we need to make use of the oscillatory behavior of the harmonic function without which the integral diverges for $\Re z\in (0,1]$.

For $z=u+\mathrm iv$, $u,v \in\mathbb R$, $|(t-i)^z|=(t^2+1)^ue^{-\alpha v}$, where $\alpha=\arg(t-i)$ so $|\alpha|<\pi$. As $z$ is in a finite radius disk, $|u|,|v|\in [a,b]$ for some constant real numbers $0<a<b$. $|(t-i)^z|>t^ae^{-\pi b}>0$, $|z|<\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.

$$|\overline F_+(x,z,R)|<\frac 1x \bigg(\frac1{R^ae^{-\pi b}}+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\int_R^\infty \frac1{t^{1+a}e^{-\pi b}}\,\mathrm dt\bigg)=e^{\pi b}\bigg(1+\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}a\bigg)\frac1{xR^a}.$$
$|\overline F_+(x,z,R)|\rightarrow 0$ as $R\rightarrow\infty$ uniformly with respect to $z\in B$. The same goes for $|\overline F_-(x,z,R)|$. So $F(x,z,R)\rightarrow F(x,z)$ as $R\rightarrow\infty$ uniformly with respect to $z\in B$ for fixed $x\in\mathbb R^+$.

QED

---

Now we proceed to evaluate the original integral.

Make the branch cut of $u^z$ in the variable $u$ along the imaginary axis. We construct a contour extending the real axis segment around the upper semicircle, with a slit cut along the imaginary axis with a keyhole around $i$. 
$$I_1(R)+I_2(R)+I_3(r,R)+I_4(r)+I_5(r,R)+I_6(R)=0,$$
where
\begin{align}
I_1(R) &= \int_{-R}^R\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}tx}}
{\left(\,t - \mathrm{i}\,\right)^z}\,\mathrm{d}t \\
I_2(R) &= \int_0^{\frac\pi2}\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}xRe^{\mathrm i\theta}}}
{\left(\,Re^{\mathrm i\theta} - \mathrm{i}\,\right)^z}iRe^{\mathrm i\theta}\,\mathrm{d}\theta \\
I_6(R) &= \int_{\frac\pi2}^\pi\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}xRe^{\mathrm i\theta}}} 
{\left(\,Re^{\mathrm i\theta} - \mathrm{i}\,\right)^z}iRe^{\mathrm i\theta}\,\mathrm{d}\theta \\
I_4(r,R) &= e^{-x}\int_{\frac\pi2}^{-\frac32\pi}\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}xre^{\mathrm i\theta}}}
{\left(re^{\mathrm i\theta}\right)^z}ire^{\mathrm i\theta}\,\mathrm{d}\theta = ie^{-x}\int_{\frac\pi2}^{-\frac32\pi}e^{ixre^{i\theta}}(re^{i\theta})^{1-z}\,\mathrm d\theta  \\
I_3(r,R) &= e^{-x}\int_R^r\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}xte^{\mathrm i\frac\pi 2}}}
{\big(te^{\mathrm i\frac\pi 2}\big)^z}e^{\mathrm i\frac\pi 2}\,\mathrm dt = -ie^{-x-i\frac\pi 2z}\int_r^R\frac{e^{-xt}}{t^z}\,\mathrm dt \\
I_5(r,R) &= e^{-x}\int_r^R\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}xte^{-\mathrm i\frac32\pi}}}
{\big(te^{-\mathrm i\frac32\pi}\big)^z}e^{-\mathrm i\frac32\pi}\,\mathrm dt = ie^{-x+i\frac32\pi z}\int_r^R\frac{e^{-xt}}{t^z}\,\mathrm dt
\end{align}

Let $z=u+iv$ for real $u$ and $v$. $|(Re^{i\theta}-i)^z|=\rho^ue^{-\alpha v}$, where $\rho:=|Re^{i\theta}-i|,\,\alpha:=\arg(Re^{i\theta}-i)$. We take the branch cut where $\alpha\in\big(-\frac32\pi,\frac12\pi\big]$

When $u>0$, $\rho>R-1$, $|(Re^{i\theta}-i)^z|>(R-1)^ue^{-\alpha v}$, since $\alpha$ is bounded from both sides, $I_2(R), I_6(R)\rightarrow 0$ as $R\rightarrow\infty$. When $u\in(0,1)$, $|(re^{i\theta})^{1-z}|=r^{1-u}e^{-\theta v}$, then $I_4(r)\rightarrow 0$ as $r\rightarrow 0^+$. $I_3(r,R)$ and $I_5(r,R)$ converge as $r\rightarrow 0,\, R\rightarrow\infty$ iff $u\in(0,1)$. For $u\in(0,1)$, 
\begin{align}
I_3(0,\infty)+I_5(0,\infty) &= -2e^{-x+i\frac\pi2z}\sin(\pi z)\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-xt}}{t^z}\,\mathrm dt \\
&= -2e^{-x+i\frac\pi2z}\sin(\pi z)x^{z-1}\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{t^z}\,\mathrm dt \\
&= -2e^{-x+i\frac\pi2z}x^{z-1}\sin(\pi z)\Gamma(1-z) \\
&= -2e^{-x+i\frac\pi2z}x^{z-1}\frac\pi{\Gamma(z)}.
\end{align}
The equating of the last integral expression with the gamma function is valid only for $u\in(0,1)$. Taking the intersection which is $u\in(0,1)$ of all the convergence sets of $z$ on all the legs,
$$F(x,z) = I_1(\infty) = e^{-x+i\frac\pi2z}x^{z-1}\frac{2\pi}{\Gamma(z)}. \tag1$$
The right hand side of equation (1) is entire with respect to $z$. By Lemma 2, $F(x,z)=I_1(\infty)$ can be analytically continued from $\Re z\in(0,1)$ to $\Re z\in(0,\infty)$.  Therefore Equation $(1)$ can be extended to the open upper plane of the complex plane $\Re z\in(0,\infty)$ for positive $x\in\mathbb R^+.$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\mrm{F}\pars{x,n} \equiv
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\expo{\ic tx} \over \pars{t - \ic}^{n/2}}\,\dd t\,,\quad
> \forall\ x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\braces{0}\,,\ n\in \mathbb{N}_{\color{#f00}{\ \geq\ 1}}}$.

---

\begin{equation}\bbox[15px,#ffe,border:1px dotted navy]{\ds{%
\begin{array}{l}
\mbox{I'll consider a 'more general' case: Namely;}
\ds{\,\,\, x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\braces{0}\,,\ n \in \mathbb{R}^{+}}.
\\[5mm]
\mbox{Lets consider,}
\\\ds{\quad
\left.\vphantom{\Large A}\mc{F}\pars{x,\alpha}
\right\vert_{~\substack{x\ \in\ \mathbb{R}\setminus{0}\\[0.5mm] \alpha\ \in\ \mathbb{R}^{\large+}}} \equiv
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\expo{\ic tx} \over \pars{t - \ic}^{\alpha/2}}\,\dd t}
\quad\mbox{where}\ z^{\alpha/2}\ \mbox{is its}\ Principal\ Branch.
\end{array}}}\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{equation}

---

\begin{align}
\mc{F}\pars{x,\alpha} & =
\expo{-x}\int_{-\infty - \ic}^{\infty - \ic}
{\expo{\ic xt} \over t^{\alpha/2}}\,\dd t
\,\,\,\stackrel{\substack{t\ =\ -\ic s\\ s\ =\ \phantom{-}\ic t\\[0.5mm] \mbox{}}}{=}\,\,\,
\expo{-x}\int_{\ic\pars{-\infty - \ic}}^{\ic\pars{\infty - \ic}}
{\expo{xs} \over \pars{-\ic s}^{\alpha/2}}\,\pars{-\ic}\,\dd s
\\[5mm] & =
-\bracks{x > 0}\ic\expo{\alpha\pi\ic/4}\expo{-x}\int_{1 - \infty\ic}^{1 + \infty\ic}
{\expo{xs} \over s^{\alpha/2}}\,\dd s\label{2}\tag{2}
\end{align}
The remaining integral is evaluated along a *key-hole contour* which
'takes care' of the $\ds{z^{\alpha/2}\mbox{-Branch-Cut}}$:
\begin{align}
\left.\int_{1 - \infty\ic}^{1 + \infty\ic}{\expo{xs} \over s^{\alpha/2}}\,\dd s
\,\right\vert_{\ x\ >\ 0} &
\,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ \epsilon\ \to\ 0^{\large +}}{\sim}\,\,\,
-\int_{-\infty}^{-\epsilon}\pars{-s}^{-\alpha/2}\expo{-\alpha\pi\ic/2}\expo{xs}
\,\dd s
\\[2mm] &
\phantom{\,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ \epsilon\ \to\ 0^{\large +}}{\sim}\,\,\,}
-\int_{\pi}^{-\pi}\epsilon^{-\alpha/2}
\expo{-\ic\alpha\theta/2}\epsilon\expo{\ic\theta}\ic\,\dd\theta
\\[2mm] &
\phantom{\,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ \epsilon\ \to\ 0^{\large +}}{\sim}\,\,\,}
-\int_{-\epsilon}^{-\infty}\pars{-s}
^{-\alpha/2}\expo{\alpha\pi\ic/2}\expo{xs}\,\dd s
\\[5mm] & =
-\expo{-\alpha\pi\ic/2}\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}s^{-\alpha/2}\expo{-xs}\,\dd s +
{2\sin\pars{\alpha\pi/2}\,\epsilon^{1 - \alpha/2} \over 1 - \alpha/2}\,\ic
\\[2mm] & +
\expo{\alpha\pi\ic/2}\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}s^{-\alpha/2}\expo{-xs}\,\dd s
\\[5mm] & =
2\ic\sin\pars{\alpha\pi \over 2}
\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}s^{-\alpha/2}\expo{-xs}\,\dd s +
{2\sin\pars{\alpha\pi/2}\epsilon^{1 - \alpha/2} \over 1 - \alpha/2}\,\ic
\end{align}

> Note that I'll can consider the case where $\ds{2 \not\mid \alpha}$ such that the case $\ds{2 \mid \alpha}$ is a 'limiting one'.

Therefore,
\begin{align}
\left.\int_{1 - \infty\ic}^{1 + \infty\ic}{\expo{xs} \over s^{\alpha/2}}\,\dd s
\,\right\vert_{\ x\ >\ 0} &
\,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ \epsilon\ \to\ 0^{\large +}}{\sim}\,\,\,
2\ic\sin\pars{\alpha\pi \over 2}\bracks{%
{1 \over x^{1 - \alpha/2}}\int_{x\epsilon}^{\infty}s^{-\alpha/2}\expo{-s}\,\dd s + {\epsilon^{1 - \alpha/2} \over 1 - \alpha/2}}
\\[5mm] & =
2\ic\sin\pars{\alpha\pi \over 2}\bracks{%
x^{\alpha/2 - 1}\Gamma\pars{1 - {\alpha \over 2},x\epsilon} +
{\epsilon^{1 - \alpha/2} \over 1 - \alpha/2}}\label{3}\tag{3}
\end{align}

> $\ds{\Gamma\pars{1 - {\alpha \over 2},x\epsilon}}$ is the
>   [Incomplete Gamma Function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.2.E2).

In the present case $\large\left(\right.$ [see $\ds{\mathbf{\color{#000}{8.7.3}}}$ in DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.7.E3) ${\large\left.\right)}$: $\ds{\pars{~1 - {\alpha \over 2} \not= 0,-1,-2,\ldots\ \mbox{or/and}\ \alpha \not= 2,4,6,\ldots~}}$ 
\begin{align}
&x^{\alpha/2 - 1}\,\Gamma\pars{1 - {\alpha \over 2},x\epsilon}
\,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ \epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}{\sim}\,\,\,
x^{\alpha/2 - 1}\,\Gamma\pars{1 - {\alpha \over 2}}- {\epsilon^{1 - \alpha/2}\expo{-x\epsilon} \over 1 - \alpha/2}\label{3.a}\tag{3.a}
\\[5mm] &
\bbx{\mbox{Note that the cases}\ \alpha = 2,4,6,\ldots\
\mbox{are 'limiting cases' of the final result.}}
\end{align}
\eqref{3} becomes, in the $\ds{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}$ limit,
\begin{align}
\left.\int_{1 - \infty\ic}^{1 + \infty\ic}{\expo{xs} \over s^{\alpha/2}}\,\dd s
\,\right\vert_{\ x\ >\ 0} & =
2\ic\sin\pars{\alpha\pi \over 2}\,x^{\alpha/2 - 1}
\,\Gamma\pars{1 - {\alpha \over 2}}
\\[5mm] & =
2\ic\sin\pars{\alpha\pi \over 2}\,x^{\alpha/2 - 1}
\,{\pi \over \Gamma\pars{\alpha/2}\sin\pars{\alpha\pi/2}} =
{2\pi\ic \over \Gamma\pars{\alpha/2}}\,x^{\alpha/2 - 1}\label{4}\tag{4}
\end{align}

---

Finally, with \eqref{2} and \eqref{4}:
$$\bbox[15px,#ffe,border:1px dotted navy]{\ds{
\left.\vphantom{\Large A}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\expo{\ic tx} \over \pars{t - \ic}^{\alpha/2}}\,\dd t
\,\right\vert_{\ \substack{x\ \in\ \mathbb{R}\setminus\braces{0}\\[0.5mm]
\alpha\ \in\ \mathbb{R}^{+}}} =
\bracks{x > 0}2\pi\,{\expo{\alpha\pi\ic/4} \over \Gamma\pars{\alpha/2}}\,\,
x^{\alpha/2 - 1}\expo{-x}}}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, the original integral does not diverge for n≥4n≥4, unlike what you have concluded. It only diverges for the deformed contour as I have puzzled in my original question. Just as I have pointed out in my conversation with reuns (Now deleted by somebody, strangely --- I hope it is not reuns himself and am wondering if and how he has the privilege.) below his incomplete answer, that we should treat nnas a complex number. We should prove first that the original integral is analytic in $\Re n>0$. (to be continued in the next comment)

Comment: (continue) Then having now shown the original integral to be equal to the analytical expression just as you have derived, use analytic continuation to equate the original integral to your first expression for all $\Re n>0$. I have worked out my solution as well two days ago, which I will also post later.

Comment: @Hans Following your comments, I'll check every thing. Thanks for your remark.

Comment: @Hans Fixed. I guess every thing is right.

Comment: The divergent problem still persists in your answer. There is a little delay in my writing up of my answer which resolves all problems as promised earlier.

Comment: @Hans I don't see any divergence. I check my result with $\texttt{Mathematica}$ and it's fine.

Comment: Each of the two terms in the bracket in the first line of equation (3) approaches infinity for $\frac\alpha 2\ge 1$ as $\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+$. As I have stated in the comments above, the reason you get the right solution in the end is in thanks only to the analytic continuation from $\Re\alpha\in(0,1)$ to $\Re\alpha\in(0,\infty)$.  There is no avoiding it. That is exactly what my answer, coming soon, will show. As for Mathematica, I think you checked the final result, but not the offending integral with it. Am I right?

Comment: No my solution (for $x > 0$) is what I wrote, plus integration by parts to obtain $n/2 \in (0,1)$ so that $\int_{-\infty-i}^{\infty-i} t^{-n/2}e^{it} dt= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} t^{-n/2}e^{it} dt$ $ = \int_0^{\infty} t^{-n/2}e^{it} dt- (-1)^{-n/2} \int_0^{\infty} t^{-n/2}e^{-it} dt $ $= i^{-n/2} \Gamma(1-n/2)- (-1)^{-n/2} (-i)^{-n/2} \Gamma(1-n/2)$. Together with Felix's contour integral it proves the reflection formula $\Gamma(s)\Gamma(1-s) = \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi s)}$. The same process applied to $\int_0^\infty \frac{t^{s-1} }{e^{it}-1}dt$ proves the functional equation for $\zeta(s)$

Comment: As promised but forgot to inform you much earlier, I have set up my answer below explicitly using analytic continuation without resorting to extra special functions. Please review. I have checked your answer again. As I said before, your answer is correct thanks to the implicit use of analytic continuation. Specifically in the step getting to Equation (3), the integral valid only in $\Re(1−\frac\alpha2)>0$ is analytically continued to the whole complex plane (only $\Re\alpha>0$ is used for the original integral which is only valid for that region) in the form of the incomplete Gamma function.

Answer (score -1):

It stays related to $\Gamma(s)$ and its properties. For $x > 0$ and $n > 0$
$$F(x)  =\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{itx}}{(t-i)^{n/2}} dt=e^{-x}\int_{-\infty-i}^{\infty-i} \frac{e^{itx}}{t^{n/2}} dt=e^{-x}x^{n/2-1}\int_{-\infty-ix}^{\infty-ix} \frac{e^{i\tau}}{\tau^{n/2}} d\tau$$
$$ =F(1) e^{1-x}x^{n/2-1}$$
For $x < 0$ I'm not sure.