# Solving the Integral: $f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left[ \frac{1}{1 + \sigma^{4} t^{2}} \right]^{\frac{L}{2}} e^{-jtx} dt$ when $L$ is odd

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, residue-calculus, branch-cuts, fractional-calculus

I want to solve the following integral when $L$ is odd:

$$
 f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left[ \frac{1}{1 + \sigma^{4} t^{2}} \right]^{\frac{L}{2}} e^{-jtx} dt
$$
which can be simplified to:
$$
 f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{ \left(1 + \sigma^{4} t^{2} \right)^{\frac{L}{2}} }  e^{jt|x|} dt
$$

So we can simplify the denominator:

$$
 \left(1 + \sigma^{4} t^{2}\right)^{\frac{L}{2}}  = \left(\sigma^{4}(t^{2} + \sigma^{-4}) \right)^{\frac{L}{2}} = \sigma^{4 \cdot \frac{L}{2}}(t^{2} + \sigma^{-4})^{\frac{L}{2}}
$$

$$
 \left(t^{2} + \sigma^{-4}\right)^{\frac{L}{2}} = \left[(t-j\sigma^{-2}) \cdot (t+j\sigma^{-2})\right]^{\frac{L}{2}} = (t-j\sigma^{-2})^{\frac{L}{2}} \cdot (t+j\sigma^{-2})^{\frac{L}{2}}
$$

So our integral becomes:

$$
 f(x) = \sigma^{-4 \cdot \frac{L}{2}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{jt|x|}}{(t-j\sigma^{-2})^{\frac{L}{2}} \cdot (t+j\sigma^{-2})^{\frac{L}{2}}  }   dt
$$

---

Here is where it gets fuzzy for me. Now when $L = 2M$
$$
 f(x) = \sigma^{-4M} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{jt|x|}}{(t-j\sigma^{-2})^{M} \cdot (t+j\sigma^{-2})^{M}  }   dt
$$
We can solve this by creating a contour $\Gamma$ in the upper half plane that encloses the pole $z = js$, where $s = \sigma^{-2}$ for ease of notation.  It turns out that:

$$
 f(x) = j s^{2M} \text{Res}\left\{ g(z) \right\}\Big|_{z = js}
$$

where:
$$
 g(z) =  \frac{e^{jz|x|}}{(z-js)^{M} \cdot (z+js)^{M}  }
$$

So now we need to evaluate the residue. We know that if $g(z)$ has a pole of order $M$ at $z=z_{0}$, then:

$$
 \text{Res}\left\{ g(z) \right\}\Big|_{z = z_{0}} = \underset{z \rightarrow z_{0}}{\text{lim}} \; \frac{1}{(M-1)!} \frac{d^{M-1}}{dz^{M-1}} \left[ (z-z_{0})^{M} g(z) \right]
$$

Now we can solve this via the Generalized Leibniz Rule and we get some answer.

---

**Question:**

What happens when $L = 2K+1$? In this case, we would have a fractional derivative, ie $M = K + \frac{1}{2}$. How do we evaluate the residue here? Is this even the right thing to do anymore?

Comment: You can see my answer to essentially the same integral https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2385235/64809.

Comment: @Hans Thank you for the link! I will go through your answer today.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align} 
\mbox{Note that}\quad\on{f}\pars{x} & \equiv \bbox[5px,#ffd]{
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\pars{1 \over 1 + \sigma^{4} t^{2}}^{L/2}
\expo{-\ic tx}\,\dd t}
\\[2mm] & =
{1 \over \sigma^{2}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\expo{-\ic\verts{\xi}t} \over \pars{1 + t^{2}}^{L/2}}
\,\dd t\,,\qquad
\xi \equiv {x \over \sigma^{2}}
\end{align}

---

With $\ds{\xi \in \mathbb{R}}$ and $\ds{L \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\left[2,\infty\right)}$, the integration is switched to an integration in the "*left complex plane*" around a key-hole contour which "takes care" of the $\ds{\root{1 + z}}$-principal branch-cut ( the arc contribution vanishes out as its radius $\ds{\to \infty}$ ). Namely, 
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\expo{-\ic\verts{\xi}t} \over \pars{1 + t^{2}}^{L/2}}
\,\dd t}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{t\ \mapsto\ \ic\,t}{=}\,\,\,&
-\ic\int_{-\infty\ic}^{\infty\ic}
{\expo{\verts{\xi}t} \over \pars{1 - t}^{L/2}\
\pars{1 + t}^{L/2}}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
\ic\int_{-\infty}^{-1}
{\expo{\verts{\xi}t} \over \pars{1 - t}^{L/2}\
\pars{-1 - t}^{L/2}\expo{\ic\pi L/2}}\,\dd t
\\[2mm] + &\
\ic\int_{-1}^{-\infty}
{\expo{\verts{\xi}t} \over \pars{1 - t}^{L/2}\
\pars{-1 - t}^{L/2}\expo{-\ic\pi L/2}}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
\ic\expo{-\ic\pi L/2}\int_{1}^{\infty}
{\expo{-\verts{\xi}t} \over \pars{1 + t}^{L/2}\
\pars{-1 + t}^{L/2}}\,\dd t
\\[2mm] - &\
\ic\expo{\ic\pi L/2}\int_{1}^{\infty}
{\expo{-\verts{\xi}t} \over \pars{1 + t}^{L/2}\
\pars{-1 + t}^{L/2}}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
2\sin\pars{\pi L \over 2}\int_{1}^{\infty}
\expo{-\verts{\xi}t}\pars{t^{2} - 1}^{-L/2}\
\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
{2^{3/2 - L/2} \over \root{\pi}}\,
\sin\pars{\pi L \over 2}\,\,\,
\verts{\xi}^{L/2 - 1/2}\,\,\,
\on{K}_{\pars{1 - L}/2}\ \pars{\verts{\xi}}
\\[2mm] &\ \Gamma\pars{1 - {L \over 2}}
\label{1}\tag{1}
\\[5mm] = &\
\root{\pi}\,{2^{3/2 - L/2} \over \Gamma\pars{L/2}}
\,\,\,\verts{\xi}^{L/2 - 1/2}\,\,\,
\on{K}_{\pars{1 - L}/2}\ \pars{\verts{\xi}}
\label{2}\tag{2}
\end{align}

---

- $\ds{\on{K}_{\nu}}$ is a
  *Modified Bessel Function*. (\ref{1}) is found with [this link](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32.E8).
- From (\ref{1}) to (\ref{2}), I used the
  [Euler Reflection Formula $\ds{\color{black}{\bf 6.1.17}}$](http://people.math.sfu.ca/%7Ecbm/aands/page_256.htm) in $\mbox{A & S}$ table.
- $\ds{L < 2}$ enforces the convergence of the Bessel related integral.

Comment: Wow thanks! Okay so I have one question -- how did you get the imaginary unit out of the integral bounds? Also it doesn't seem like you actually used the fact that $L$ was odd..

Comment: @TheDude a) Because $\mathrm{d}\left(\mathrm{i}t\right) = \mathrm{i}\,\mathrm{d}t$. b) I decided to consider a $real$ $L$ to get a general result.

Comment: @FelixMartin Okay, thank you for the explanation -- so if L > 2, then this method fails?